# How to log SQL Queries

Tags: entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I want to log SQL Queries, to examine what exactly is my LINQ queries doing to understand how can I improve it.

But I can't find how to logging it.

Comment: It's baked right into EF. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx). You might also consider [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/).

Comment: Read this [article](https://romiller.com/2016/02/11/ef6-x-correlating-poor-performing-sql-to-application-code/)

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this:
Change DbContextConfigurer in EntityFramework project 
as:

```
 public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext> builder, string connectionString, **ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = null**)
    {
        **builder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);**

        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }
```

Then add in file MyProjectEntityFrameworkCoreModule.cs into PreInitiallize section

```
public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        if (!SkipDbContextRegistration)
        {
            Configuration.Modules.AbpEfCore().AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(options =>
            {
                if (options.ExistingConnection != null)
                {

                    TestDbContextConfigurer.Configure(options.DbContextOptions, options.ExistingConnection);
                }
                else
                {
                    **var loggerFactory = IocManager.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>();**
                    TestDbContextConfigurer.Configure(options.DbContextOptions, options.ConnectionString,**loggerFactory**);
                }
            });
        }

        //Uncomment below line to write change logs for the entities below:
        //Configuration.EntityHistory.Selectors.Add("TestEntities", typeof(OrganizationUnit), typeof(Role), typeof(Tenant));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MSSQL with EF and intend to troubleshoot how LINQ is being translated into SQL statement. You can try SQL Profiler that comes together with MSSQL Database Engine

With SQL Profiler, you are able to record and trace tsql event in it. With proper isolation of the LINQ call in your application, you can trace the SQL statement received by the Database engine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/tsql-event-category?view=sql-server-2017